# MS-Access -> OLEDB -> DataTable -> DataGridView memory leak

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I'm writing a thick client to an MS-Access(2016) database.

One of my forms retrieves data from the database on form loading into a datagridview. The issue is that after closing this form, the memory usage doesnt drop back to idle. App uses about 20mb before opening this form, after is about 200mb, and after closing the form pretty much stays at 200mb. But if i open it again it will consume an additional 200mb.

I'm using using block almost everywhere, tried explicitly nulling the datatable, call garbage collector, but nothing helps.

```
//This is the funcion being called on Form load event

    public static DataTable oledb_rs(string command)
            {

                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
                { 
                    conn.ConnectionString = Connection.ConnStr();
                    conn.Open();

                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                    {

                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = command;


                        using (OleDbDataAdapter rs = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                            {
                                rs.Fill(dt);
                                return dt;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }



            }
    //The Form load event
    using (DataTable megalldt = Connection.oledb_rs("SELECT * FROM Megallapitasok"))
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = megalldt;
                }

    //The form close event
        dataGridView1.Dispose();
        this.Dispose();

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
        GC.Collect();
```

Comment: How are you determining the amount of memory used? Please try this: open the form that makes the memory usage spike, close it down, **minimize the application** and have a look at the memory footprint.

Comment: If you 1) close the form, then 2) run your collect code, you should get (most of) the memory that was used in the form (datagrid, datatable, datarows, datarowviews). I've written a small tool that allows you to watch how many instances of a type are used in a specific process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43854093/viewing-garbage-collection-history-in-c-sharp-vs2015/44484627#44484627

Comment: @SimonMourier, It turns out, dataGridView1.Dispose(); doesnt disposes everything as it supposed to, I had to replace that with this line: dataGridView1.DataSource=null; ....

Now, after the second form closes, I call the GC, and the memory usage drops back, very close to idle. Please form this to an answere so i can award the bounty to you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridView.Dispose() doesn't do much about the datasource (and its underlying data), it's more focused on disposing graphical (GDI+) objects, visual columns, cells, pens, brushes, etc. But it has a reference on it.

So, what you need to reduce memory is ensure nothing holds a reference to the DataTable (the instance you created) anymore. There are many ways to do it, it depends how your objects are created, what instance references what, how they go out of scope, etc.

The most simple solution is to close the 2nd form, then, dataGridView1 will not be referenced anymore (it was referenced by the 2nd form), same for its DataSource instance. Then you can run your GC collection code.